# StageVideo not showing live stream video (non-H264)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to use Flash's StageVideo object through the example ActionScript file in this page (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html), the problem is it's just showing up a black screen (no video) for live streams which are not using the H264 codec? and also it is not even throwing up a StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE event to say that it cannot play the stream. Actually it can seem to play the stream because I can hear audio but it is just unable to show up any video, anybody encountered this scenario before?

Someone commented on some other sites to check if the "Enable Hardware Acceleration" in the Flash settings is checked, and I can confirm that it is checked, again this is only happening whenever I'm viewing a non-H264 stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not I had the exact same issue as you and you will hate the solution.

Set the background alpha to 0. Turns out the stagevideo object lives behind the background of the container and has to have a 0 alpha to "show" through

Comment: wow, i haven't tried this one out but let's see, I'm not doing this StageVideo thing anymore now but this should be helpful in the near future, thank you for sharing.

Comment: This does not explain no `RENDER_STATE` being fired.